# Requesting font awesome file from nodeJs is sending back wrong data/file

Tags: javascript, node.js, curl, httprequest, font-awesome

my application: When you send a request from a browser to my node server, my node server will request an origin website, download all of its static files (including code) and server them back to the user. Next time you visit my node server it will server all the content back from node instead of requesting the origin.

When i make a request for a font awesome file from node

```
http://example.com/modules/megamenu/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff?v=4.2.0
```

The file's content is different from when i request the same url with cUrl.

This is causing this error in the browser when i return the file from node back to the browser:

```
Failed to decode downloaded font: http://nodeDomain.test/modules/megamenu/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff?v=4.2.0
```

If i copy and paste the content from the file i requested via curl into the file stored on my node server, the error disappears and all the font awesome stuff works.

Here are the headers I am sending with the request to the origin server from node.

```
{ 
connection: 'keep-alive',
pragma: 'no-cache',
'cache-control': 'no-cache',
'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_5)AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/43.0.2357.130 Safari/537.36',
accept: '*/*',
referer: 'http://example.com/modules/megamenu/css/font-awesome.min.css',
'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.8',
cookie: 'PrestaShop-a30a9934ef476d11b.....' 

}
```

I tried to see what headers where being sent when doing the curl request from command line but i cannot figure out how to do it.

______Node code used to fetch file_______

```
Url: in options is the one stated above
headers: are the browsers request headers

var options = {
url: originRequestPath,
headers: requestHeaders
}

var originPage = rquest(options);
var responseBody = '';
var resHeads = '';

originPage.on('response', function(res)
{
   //store response headers locally
}

originPage.on('data', function(chunk) 
{       
    responseBody += chunk;
});                                                                               

originPage.on('end', function() 
{
    storeData.storePageData(storeFilePath, responseBody);
}); 

__________Store Function below________________

exp.storePageData = function(storePath, pageContent)
{
  fs.outputFile(storePath, pageContent, function(err) {
        if(err){ console.log(err)}
  });

}
```

Comment: Possibly an encoding problem when you app saves the file from the origin, but no way of really knowing without seeing some code. If you can show us some of your app's fetching code, that would be helpful.

Comment: Ok grate ill ad the fetching code in a second just having a smoke quick :P

Comment: Iv added the code i use to fetch the file this is the basics of it i have ALOT of code inside the functions that does stuff with the data, but that isnt to do with the issue so iv left it out.

Comment: I assume you're using node's built in `http.request`? If you're not doing anything with the file as it's downloaded, you might find the convenience method `http.get` (https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_get_options_callback) easier to work with. That may eliminate anything that's going wrong with your fetching code (though it looks ok to me). If you're still having problems, post the code used to store the file. Ideally, chuck your entire app up in a gist or pastebin. From what you've said, there can't be *that* much of it.

Comment: yup i'm using http.request ill try using http.get and see what happens. unfortunately i cannot post the full code online due to contracts (this is not a personal project). Thanks for your help.

Comment: Fair enough. Some storage code (or approximation thereof) would be useful in any case.

Comment: Added the code that stores the file. Please note this works for every single file on the website other than this 1 font awesome file. Thanks for looking at this for me, been doing my head in for a few hours now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the problem with your code is you are converting your buffer output to utf8 string. since you are adding buffer with empty string `responseBody += chunk;` that buffer is converted to utf-8 string. Thus you are losing some data for binary files. Try this way:

```
var originPage = rquest(options);
var chunks = []

originPage.on('response', function(res)
{
   //store response headers locally
}

originPage.on('data', function(chunk) 
{       
    chunks.push(chunk)
});                                                                               

originPage.on('end', function() 
{       
     var data = Buffer.concat(chunks)
    //send data to browser and store content locally
});
```

Comment: this sounds pretty likely to me - I assume using http.get would solve this also.

Comment: :O that makes sense let me try. if not ill try http.get